# Cannot set variable from within node.js request callback

Tags: node.js, firebase, request

I'm using Hive to review images being sent to our server. When I get a hit off of the image I want to be able to let the frontend know so I can show a warning message. I set this variable "goodImage" to be true if the image is fine and false if the image is bad. When I return the variable, it always returns undefined. I've tried awaiting the request, but it doesn't work. Any help here would be much appreciated.

```
async function checkImage(imgUrl, uid){
    let goodImage
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://api.thehive.ai/api/v2/task/sync',
        headers: {
            'accept': 'application/json',
            'authorization': `token ${functions.config().hive.key}`
        },
        form: {
            'image_url': imgUrl,
        },
        json: true
    };
    try {
        request(options, async function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                console.error(error);
                throw new HttpsError('internal', 'Pick another Image.');
            }
            let codeViolations = [];
            if(body.status[0] !== undefined && body.status[0].response.output[0] !== undefined){
            const classes = body.status[0].response.output[0].classes;
            for(let i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
                if(looking_for_sexual_tags.includes(classes[i].class)){
                    if(classes[i].score > .9) {
                        if(!codeViolations.includes('Nudity, Pornography, and Other Sexual Content')){
                            codeViolations.push('Nudity, Pornography, and Other Sexual Content');
                        }
                    }
                } else if(looking_for_hate_tags.includes(classes[i].class)){
                    if(classes[i].score > .9) {
                        if(!codeViolations.includes('Hateful Conduct and Harassment')){
                            codeViolations.push('Hateful Conduct and Harassment');
                        }
                    }
                } else if(looking_for_violence_tags.includes(classes[i].class)){
                    if(classes[i].score > .9) {
                        if(!codeViolations.includes('Violence and Threats')){
                            codeViolations.push('Violence and Threats');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(codeViolations.length > 0) {
                //await banUser(uid, 'Inappropriate Image', codeViolations);
                goodImage = false;
            } else { 
                goodImage = true;
            }
        } 
        else{
            goodImage = true;
        }
        });
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error('Error acquiring image tags from hive.');
        console.log(e);
        return undefined;
    }
    return goodImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not awaiting the request, you are using callbacks. The statement `return goodImage;` will be executed before the request has finished. There's a couple of ways to fix this, so for example you can wrap the callback in a custom promise:

```
async function checkImage(imgUrl, uid) {
  let goodImage;
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api.thehive.ai/api/v2/task/sync',
    headers: {
      'accept': 'application/json',
      'authorization': `token ${functions.config().hive.key}`,
    },
    form: {
      'image_url': imgUrl,
    },
    json: true,
  };
  try {
    const responseBody = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request(options, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
          console.error(error);
          return reject(new HttpsError('internal', 'Pick another Image.'));
        }
        resolve(body);
      });
    });

    let codeViolations = [];
    if (responseBody.status[0] !== undefined && responseBody.status[0].response.output[0] !== undefined) {
      const classes = responseBody.status[0].response.output[0].classes;
      for (let i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
        if (looking_for_sexual_tags.includes(classes[i].class)) {
          if (classes[i].score > .9) {
            if (!codeViolations.includes('Nudity, Pornography, and Other Sexual Content')) {
              codeViolations.push('Nudity, Pornography, and Other Sexual Content');
            }
          }
        } else if (looking_for_hate_tags.includes(classes[i].class)) {
          if (classes[i].score > .9) {
            if (!codeViolations.includes('Hateful Conduct and Harassment')) {
              codeViolations.push('Hateful Conduct and Harassment');
            }
          }
        } else if (looking_for_violence_tags.includes(classes[i].class)) {
          if (classes[i].score > .9) {
            if (!codeViolations.includes('Violence and Threats')) {
              codeViolations.push('Violence and Threats');
            }
          }
        }
      }
      if (codeViolations.length > 0) {
        //await banUser(uid, 'Inappropriate Image', codeViolations);
        goodImage = false;
      } else {
        goodImage = true;
      }
    } else {
      goodImage = true;
    }

  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error acquiring image tags from hive.');
    console.log(e);
    return undefined;
  }
  return goodImage;
}
```

Note: you should really consider exchanging the `request`-library for another http-library as it has been [deprecated](https://github.com/request/request#deprecated). We currently use [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent#install) for our REST-api and are really happy with it (fast, simple). It also supports promises out of the box, allowing you to simply do: `const response = await superagent(...);` instead of having to wind up your own promise.

Comment: using the code you gave gives a few syntax errors, I ironed out most of them, but
```
const {body} = requestPromise;
```
gives the error Property 'body' does not exist on type '{}'

and if I don't wrap body in curly braces, I get an error here
```
const classes = body.status[0].response.output[0].classes;
```

Comment: Simplified it and removed object destructuring, since we can directy resolve the `body`. Can you please check again?

Comment: when I change the name from body and get it to run, it isn't defined

Comment: Changed it to `responseBody` . If it does not work, you can edit your question and post the updated code and I'll have another look.

Comment: I changed away from using request like you suggested and it works now. Posted the working code as an answer.

Comment: Ok, can you please accept my answer though? Would appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: Note that `request-promise` also depends on `request`, so the problem with the deprecation is not gone :)

Answer (score 0):

I switched away from using request as suggested by @eol. I used request-promise and it worked like a charm, here is the full functional code.

```
async function checkImage(imgUrl, uid) {
    let goodImage;
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      uri: 'https://api.thehive.ai/api/v2/task/sync',
      headers: {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'authorization': `token ${functions.config().hive.key}`,
      },
      form: {
        'image_url': imgUrl,
      },
      json: true,
    };
    try {
      const body = await rp(options);
      let codeViolations = [];
      if (body.status[0] !== undefined && body.status[0].response.output[0] !== undefined) {
        const classes = body.status[0].response.output[0].classes;
        for (let i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
          if (looking_for_sexual_tags.includes(classes[i].class)) {
            if (classes[i].score > .9) {
              if (!codeViolations.includes('Nudity, Pornography, and Other Sexual Content')) {
                codeViolations.push('Nudity, Pornography, and Other Sexual Content');
              }
            }
          } else if (looking_for_hate_tags.includes(classes[i].class)) {
            if (classes[i].score > .9) {
              if (!codeViolations.includes('Hateful Conduct and Harassment')) {
                codeViolations.push('Hateful Conduct and Harassment');
              }
            }
          } else if (looking_for_violence_tags.includes(classes[i].class)) {
            if (classes[i].score > .9) {
              if (!codeViolations.includes('Violence and Threats')) {
                codeViolations.push('Violence and Threats');
              }
            }
          }
        }
        if (codeViolations.length > 0) {
          //await banUser(uid, 'Inappropriate Image', codeViolations);
          goodImage = false;
        } else {
          goodImage = true;
        }
      } else {
        goodImage = true;
      }
  
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Error acquiring image tags from hive.');
      console.log(e);
      return undefined;
    }
    return goodImage;
  }
```

Comment: Note that request-promise also depends on request, so the problem with the deprecation is not gone :)